# Transparent background file download from S3

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-s3, streaming

I am trying to permit a python app to access various locations in a many-GB file stored in S3. I'd like to create a drop-in replacement file-like object that intelligently downloads chunks of data from S3 in a separate thread to meet seek() and read() requests.

Is there a simple data structure I can use to store arbitrary intervals of the file?

It must support O(log n) look-up and O(n) insertion (n=number of chunks, not size of file). It will also need to support quickly querying for *gaps* so that the load thread can efficiently find the next chunk it should download. This is currently not supported by things like [SortedCollection](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/), suggesting I may need to manually use bisect_* in a new container.

Example usage is:

```
import os
import time
from bigfile import BigFile

chunksize = (2**20)*64 # 64MB

bf = BigFile('my_bucket', 'key_name', chunksize=chunksize)

# read from beginning (blocks until first chunk arrives)
bf.read(100)

# continues downloading subsequent chunks in background
time.sleep(10)

# seek into second chunk and read (should not block)
bf.seek(blocksize, os.SEEK_SET)
bf.read(100)

# seek far into the file
bf.seek(blocksize*100 + 54, os.SEEK_SET) # triggers chunk download starting at new location
bf.read(100) # blocks until chunk arrives

# seek back to beginning (should not block, already have this chunk)
bf.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
bf.read(100)

# read entire rest of file (blocks until all chunks are downloaded)
bf.read()
```

Comment: A question would be nice as well ;)

Comment: "Is there a simple data structure I can use to store arbitrary intervals of the file?" is the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation uses chunks of fixed size and offsets. If the chunks are very large and the network is very slow, reads may block for a long time (consider a read starting at the last byte of a chunk, it would have to wait for the entire previous chunk to load, then the next chunk).

Ideally we could use chunks of arbitrary size and location, so we can optimize loads to start at exactly the read point. But below is a good 80% solution.

```
import boto
import threading
import tempfile
import os

DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 2**20 * 64 # 64 MB per request

class BigFile(object):
    def __init__(self, file_obj, file_size, chunksize=DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE, start=True):
        self._file_obj = file_obj
        self._file_size = file_size
        self._lock = threading.RLock()
        self._load_condition = threading.Condition(self._lock)
        self._load_run = True
        self._loc = 0
        self._chunk_size = chunksize
        chunk_count = self._file_size // self._chunk_size
        chunk_count += 1 if self._file_size % self._chunk_size else 0
        self._chunks = [None for _ in xrange(chunk_count)]
        self._load_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._load)
        if start:
            self._load_thread.start()

    def _chunk_loc(self):
        ' Returns (chunk_num, chunk_offset) for a given location in the larger file '
        return self._loc // self._chunk_size, self._loc % self._chunk_size

    def _load_chunk(self, chunk_num):
        tf = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        start_idx = chunk_num * self._chunk_size
        self._file_obj.seek(start_idx)
        tf.write(self._file_obj.read(self._chunk_size))
        with self._lock:
            self._chunks[chunk_num] = (tf, tf.tell()) # (tempfile, size)
            self._load_condition.notify()

    def _load(self):
        while self._load_run:
            # check current chunk, load if needed
            with self._lock:
                chunk_num, _ = self._chunk_loc()
                chunk_and_size = self._chunks[chunk_num]
            if chunk_and_size is None:
                self._load_chunk(chunk_num)

            # find next empty chunk
            for i in xrange(len(self._chunks)):
                cur_chunk = chunk_num + i
                    cur_chunk %= len(self._chunks) # loop around
                if self._chunks[cur_chunk] is None:
                    self._load_chunk(cur_chunk)
                    break
            else:
                # all done, stop thread
                break

    def seek(self, loc, rel=os.SEEK_SET):
        with self._lock:
            if rel == os.SEEK_CUR:
                self._loc += loc
            elif rel == os.SEEK_SET:
                self._loc = loc
            elif rel == os.SEEK_END:
                self._loc = self._file_size + loc

    def read(self, bytes_to_read):
        ret = []
        with self._lock:
            chunk_num, chunk_offset = self._chunk_loc()
            while (bytes_to_read > 0 or bytes_to_read == -1) and chunk_num < len(self._chunks):
                while not self._chunks[chunk_num]:
                    self._load_condition.wait()
                chunk, size = self._chunks[chunk_num]
                cur_chunk_bytes = min(self._chunk_size-chunk_offset, bytes_to_read, size)
                chunk.seek(chunk_offset, os.SEEK_SET)
                data = chunk.read(cur_chunk_bytes)
                ret.append(data)
                bytes_to_read -= len(data)
                chunk_num += 1
        return ''.join(ret)

    def start(self):
        self._load_thread.start()

    def join(self):
        self._load_thread.join()

    def stop(self):
        self._load_run = False

class S3RangeReader:
    def __init__(self, key_obj):
        self._key_obj = key_obj
        self.size = self._key_obj.size
        self._pos = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def seek(self, pos, rel=os.SEEK_SET):
        if rel == os.SEEK_CUR:
            self._pos += pos
        elif rel == os.SEEK_SET:
            self._pos = pos
        elif rel == os.SEEK_END:
            self._pos = self.size + pos

    def read(self, bytes=-1):
        if bytes == 0 or self._pos >= self.size:
            return ''
        else:
            if bytes == -1:
                bytes = self.size
            headers = {'Range': 'bytes=%s-%s' % (self._pos, self._pos + bytes - 1)} # S3 ranges are closed ranges: [start,end]
            return self._key_obj.get_contents_as_string(headers=headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    key = boto.s3_connect().get_bucket('mybucket').get_key('my_key')
    reader = S3RangeReader(key)
    bf = BigFile(reader, len(reader)) # download starts by default
    bf.seek(1000000)
    bf.read(100) # blocks
    bf.seek(0)
    bf.read(100) # should not block
```